# How does `matplotlib._logged_cached` work?

Tags: python, matplotlib, decorator, local-variables

The following code is from Matplotlib's `__init__` file:

```
def _logged_cached(fmt, func=None):
    """
    Decorator that logs a function's return value, and memoizes that value.

    After ::

        @_logged_cached(fmt)
        def func(): ...

    the first call to *func* will log its return value at the DEBUG level using
    %-format string *fmt*, and memoize it; later calls to *func* will directly
    return that value.
    """
    if func is None:  # Return the actual decorator.
        return functools.partial(_logged_cached, fmt)

    called = False
    ret = None

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(**kwargs):
        nonlocal called, ret
        if not called:
            ret = func(**kwargs)
            called = True
            _log.debug(fmt, ret)
        return ret

    return wrapper
```

Question: How does the **caching** in the above function work? Won't the local variables of `_logged_cached` be reinitialised on each call?

As I understand it, the local variables are deleted after the function returns (right?). If so, then the caching won't work. Yet, the documentation says the decorated function will return the same object on each call -- and it does. How, though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the caching works is because of a concept called closures. Your understanding is correct that local variables are deleted after a function exits but the variables used here for caching aren't local to the inner function.

If you use the `_logged_cached` decorator on a function, the function will essentially be replaced by the nested function `wrapper`. This `wrapper` function when returned becomes a closure (a function object) which will remember the non-local variables in the enclosing scope. So it will essentially have a mapping that remembers the variables `called` and `ret`. Each time you call the function object (the decorated function) the inner scope will have `called` and `ret` available to use.

Normally they would only be usable as read-only in the inner function but by using the keyword `nonlocal`, the inner function is actually able to change/update the values of the variables `called` and `ret` in the closure. Thus that mapping we mentioned before saved in the function object gets its values updated and each subsequential call to the decorated function will make use of those same values.

Comment: For those wondering where exactly those variables are stored, it's in `wrapper.__closure__` (where `wrapper` is the function returned when `_logged_cached` is called with a function object as its `func` argument). `wrapper.__closure__`, in this case, will be a tuple of [Cell](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/cell.html) objects.